# Concurrent beginBackgroundTaskWithName on push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-task, background-fetch

I want to start and background task on receipt of a push notification.  So far I have the following:

```
  -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

  NSString* taskName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PushNotificationTask-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

  NSLog(@"Starting bg-task for push notification %@", taskName);

  self.pnBgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:taskName expirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Expiring bg-task for push notification %@", taskName);

    [application endBackgroundTask:self.pnBgTask];
    self.pnBgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  }];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // do work here

    NSLog(@"Ending bg-task for push notification %@", taskName);
    [application endBackgroundTask:self.pnBgTask];
    self.pnBgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  });
```

In the situation where a push notification arrives before the background task of the previous one has finished, this code fails because one task will overwrite the other.

Can someone suggest a good pattern to resolve this problem?

Comment: if possible explain in proper way. What to do?

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/npomfret/7e33e9e88da1a4ae2bcf38a51e68f19d - i'm in the process of testing, but it attempts to keep track of multiple background tasks ids so that more than one can run at once.